# Mongo DB Cant Start

Tags: mongodb

Evening we have had a mongodb running fine for a few weeks and all of sudden it has gone down.

We are unable to start it back up as it is complaining that the "dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist" I've tried routing through the documentation and have seen others suggest using the dbpath flag, however still no luck.

We are starting it with "sudo service mongodb start" and the config file dbpath config points to a directory with our db in.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Gary

Comment: This isn't related to programming: better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying running mongodb --config  to ensure your config file is correct? Also have your recently updated your packages?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. No I haven't updated anything recently. The app has been running in a production envirmonment for a while without issues. I did in the end get it back up and running using the --dbpath flag to my existing db (missed the quotes previously). Saying that its the same url that is stored in the config file on the server so not sure why this has stopped working. Now its running I will try running your suggestion as soon as we get the opportunity to bring it down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step by Step:

- set your mongo bin under the path
- create a new folder under
- your home directory eg. `mkdir ~/db`
- go to your home directory eg. `cd ~`
- start up your mongo db  eg. `mongod --dbpath ./db`

If you are asking why /data/db/ this is gone, and I have no idea.

Comment: UNfortunately this wasn't an option to start a new db as entrants had already begun being entered. The actual db was still there it was just failing to see it. As explained above I did in the end get it up and running with --dbpath eventually but still doesn't explain why it can't get it from the config. Thanks for your input.